# Как обработать input во vue

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Я только новичок  во vue  и я хотел бы узнать, как можно обработать input на наличие цифр в нем через composition API.

То есть, если пользователь вписывает цифры в поле оно выделяется красным, если только текст, то все норм.
Во vue не читает onchange и не видит функцию.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const name = ref('')
const surname = ref('')
</script>

<template>
   <input type="text" v-model="name" onchange="check()" placeholder="Имя">
   <input type="text" v-model="surname" placeholder="Фамилия">
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для инпута определяется событие @input, на каждый ввод в поле срабатывает проверка в методе check() где происходит проверка на цифры и установка специального флага hasNumbers, который добавляет класс :class="{ 'has-numbers': hasNumbers }" на котором висит стиль выделяющий инпут красным цветом.

```
   <script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    
    const name = ref('');
    const surname = ref('');
    const hasNumbers = ref(false);
    
    function check() {
      hasNumbers.value = /\d/.test(name.value);
    }
    </script>
    
    <template>
      <input type="text" v-model="name" @input="check" :class="{ 'has-numbers': hasNumbers }" placeholder="Имя">
      <input type="text" v-model="surname" placeholder="Фамилия">
    </template>
```

```
    <style>
    .has-numbers {
      color: #ff0000;
      border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    }
    </style>
```